# Do I can Symbol.iterator in Object by prototype?"JavaScript"

Tags: javascript, object, iterator, symbols

Why I can't add Symbol.iterator into Object like that

```
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator];

let obj = {num: 1 , type : ' :) '}
for (let p of obj) {
  console.log(p);
}
// TypeError: obj is not iterable
```

Comment: You didn't assign anything to `Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign a generator function to `Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`.

```js
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  for (let k in this) {
    yield this[k];
  }
};

let obj = {
  num: 1,
  type: ' :) '
}
for (let p of obj) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you didnt actually assign anything to `Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` - if you do assign an iterator function that does somethign sensible I think it might work as you expected

```js
Object.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
  for(let entry of Object.entries(this))
     yield entry
};

let obj = {num: 1 , type : ' :) '}
for (let [k,v] of obj) {
  console.log(k,v);
}

// another way
console.log(...obj)
```